# American renting a car in Europe - what's different compared to domestic rentals?

Tags: us-citizens, car-rentals, solo-travel

I'm planning a solo travel trip to Brussels and was wondering if any American / US Drivers license holders have experience booking an airport car rental through Expedia or similar. Currently, I reserved a car for $165/week, with unlimited mileage - I plan to drive around Belgium within a 1 hour radius and after a few days, drive to Netherlands.

I did not add collision insurance and have a pretty comprehensive American insurance coverage. Is there anything additional I should consider? My only concern is being forcefully 'upsold' or taken advantage of at the counter upon arrival or being told they cannot offer me the car at the Expedia reserve price. Was wondering if anyone can share their experience renting a car in Europe with an American DL / Passport.

Note, the car company I used was Hertz, which is pretty well known, so I don't expect any surprises, but would like to be well-prepared should anything come up.

Comment: Did you book an automatic? If not, can you handle a manual/stick shift driven car?

Comment: I actually prefer a manual transmission, so thats no issue :D Great point though, rental cars are manual transmissions by default in Europe.

Comment: I find the best way to avoid any upsells is by joining the rental agency loyalty programme and setting preferences there. I book direct and rarely even communicate with agents. I'm EU though so can't answer your question from a US PoV

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Especially with larger companies, you should have no issues at all.
I had several dozen rentals all across Europe (with US Drivers License, and nobody ever wanted to see a passport); never any questions or issues. The worst to expect is a funny accent, but they are all used to handling many US visitors every day.

You need to make sure that you know which insurances you need, as other countries have other rules (in the US, a *Driver* is insured, in Europe, often the *car* is insured, not the driver). Check *upfront* if your credit card covers comprehensible insurance, or if your US insurance covers you in the rental car. 
They do try to upsell, but if you give the impression that you know what you want, they are not annoying at all.

Note also that small rental car damages are seen quite different in Europe - any little scratch that National or Enterprise or Hertz would ignore in the US may result in three or four digits repair bills.

Comment: Thats a great relief, thanks for the feedback. Regarding insurance coverage, I have Geico, which doesn't extend to Europe, however, my Visa credit card has an added benefit of collision insurance. Should that be all that I need or will I be forced to purchase additional liability insurance at the counter? Basically, I am certain I have a good car damage and theft insurance, but thats all I have.

Comment: You won’t be forced. You just need to understand which risk you take when you decline it. They make you sign that you decline potentially.

Comment: I am using Hertz actually, is it really the case that Hertz in Europe would operate differently and charge for even minor damages / scratches that would be ignored in the US? When you rented a car in EU did you accept the insurance that was offered at the counter?

Comment: Definitely. I have several bills I paid to prove it. It’s not Hertz, it’s the European culture about cars and ‘damage’.

Comment: Oh wow, thats good to know. Appreciate the advice. Isn't insurance really steep on rentals in EU, like $25/day?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend $25 a day sounds about right to me for both Europe and the US.

Comment: In most European countries, third party liability insurance is mandatory and linked to the car, not the driver. If you rent a car in Europe, liability insurance is included in the 'base price'. What you can buy extra is usually insurance covering self-inflicted damage to the car (also scratches, rock chip, etc.) and theft. Such additional insurance can be quite expensive, but it can also get very expensive not having such insurance.

Comment: There are companies offering separate free-standing annual policies to cover the extra liability (in the UK) but not sure if they sell to US citizens. It is likely to be (much) cheaper than even a week from the hire company.

Comment: All rentals in Europe include mandatory basic insurance which covers the minimum legal requirement. However there is usually a high excess on the basic policy (US$1000+). You should look for a car hire excess insurance policy (in the US, or which allows US residents to purchase it). This is effectively insuring the excess rather than the car itself. In the event of damage to the car you would pay the car hire company (up to the maximum of the excess) and then claim this back from the excess insurance company. I rent cars a lot & this is what I do. My policy costs me around US$60 a year.

Comment: Also check if crossing the border is allowed with your rental, some companies don't like you crossing borders. As stated before I'm pretty sure that 3rd cover is mandatory in Belgium.

Answer (score 2):

Several years back I rented through Hertz to drive from Faro to and around the Algarve in Portugal.
I booked the rental car (manual transmission) locally in Boston and purchased a International Drivers License from AAA (15-20.00 USD) just to cover any potential veracity or legal challenges using my US issued Drivers License. In addition to upgrading the rental coverage on my travel insurance.

If your first time driving in the EU. Perhaps you might find the link below helpful.

As an aside don't make the mistake I did. Before you drive out of the destination airport. Ask about hours and locations for refueling your rental along the route(s) you have planned.
Safe travels!
http://traveltips.usatoday.com/driving-instructions-europe-27544.html